# How can i push logs from solarwinds SAM to view analytics using Azure monitor

Tags: azure, monitor, solarwinds-orion

I am trying to integrate solarwinds with azure monitor so that the az monitor could pull logs from the solarwinds and i could view telemetrics in SAM

I could only find ways to use solarwinds to monitor azure monitor using AppOptics which is the reverse of what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
How can i push logs from solarwinds SAM to view analytics using Azure monitor?
```

No, you cannot push the logs from **solarwinds SAM** to view analytics using **Azure monitor**.

SolarWinds SAM is a  powerful **Azure monitoring tool**
which is used for complete monitoring of azure environment.

It will Monitor both  the complex Azure environment and other infrastructure for more contextual overviews, insights into systems, applications, and infrastructure performance, regardless of where they reside.

You can refer this [link](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/ipmonitor/content/log_files.htm) to View the log files of solarwinds SAM.